# JSDoc long line formatting in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

The [DocBlockr package for sublime](https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-jsdocs) offers the feature "Inside a comment block, hit Alt+Q to wrap the lines to make them fit within your rulers." That's very handy when editing multiline file descriptions. Is there any good way to do that in Visual Studio Code? Manually reformating line breaks and initial asterisks within a JSDoc comment is a pain in the neck.

Comment: Did you find any solution? It seems to me like a completely obvious function that must be already present. I mean even eclipse can do this with javadoc.